# Visiblox plot missing after changing axis from log to linear

Tags: plot, visiblox

I have a exponential curve shown as a green line, displayed on a log (Y) - linear (X) axis like this:
[image]

I try to change the axis plot style from log-linear to linear-linear like this:

```
var tmpCalibrationChartXAxis = new LinearAxis();
var tmpCalibrationChartYAxis = new LinearAxis();
tmpCalibrationChartXAxis.Range = new DoubleRange(this.minX * 0.9, this.maxX * 1.1);
tmpCalibrationChartYAxis.Range = new DoubleRange(this.minY * 0.9, this.maxY * 1.1);
this.CalibrationChartXAxis = tmpCalibrationChartXAxis;
this.CalibrationChartYAxis = tmpCalibrationChartYAxis;
```

where CalibrationChartXAxis and CalibrationChartYAxis are data bound via WPF to a Visiblox Chart XAxis and YAxis. What I get is a plot without the green curve displayed as seen below. [image]

If I change the plot axis back to the initial configuration the green curve reappears again. Please note that I do not change the plot data series at any moment while applying those changes. I do not understand why the curve is missing when using a linear-linear scale. How can I fix that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you talking about the green line that shows up in the log plot, but not the linear plot?  Do you have ShowLines set to true on your LineSeries?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the green line. I do not change the line data series at all while switching between axis so I do not understand why it shows in one case but but does not in the other.

Comment: Can you post your code so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: It looks like the green line is a bug in the first place.  It certainly does not fit the data points.  Try messing with setting ShowLine to true/false and see what happens in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a WPF rendering issue (the bug only happens when the Y values get very large, if you truncate your data the bug disappears). Using RasterLineSeries or a DirectXLineSeries instead of DataSeries won’t encounter this issue.